# Docker swarm health check fail kills container - exited 0

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm running a basic node app image built with the following Dockerfile

```
# Use the official image as a parent image.
FROM node:current

# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the file from your host to your current location.
COPY package.json .

# Run the command inside your image filesystem.
RUN npm install

# Inform Docker that the container is listening on the specified port at runtime.
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the specified command within the container.
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

# Copy the rest of your app's source code from your host to your image filesystem.
COPY . .

#HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=3s CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8080/health || exit 1
```

I run the docker swarm service using the following docker stack file:

```
version: "3"
services:

  webapp:
    image: testapp:broken
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 3
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

Everything works fine if the curl command succeeds. But if I remove the `/health` route, the status does not go from `health: starting` to `unhealthy`, it straight up kills the container.

How can I solve this? I've also tried the
`test: ["CMD", "curl -f http://localhost:8080/health || exit 1"]` approach, but no luck.

Edit: The container appears as Exited

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
73fce379163c        testapp:broken      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Exited (0) 6 minutes ago                       testapp_webapp.1.oqdg1uuxgk52end0h9ady7tpz
```

with the following state:

```
"State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-05-19T13:17:10.39992571Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2020-05-19T13:17:42.824012295Z",
            "Health": {
                "Status": "unhealthy",
                "FailingStreak": 3,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2020-05-19T13:17:20.400938593Z",
                        "End": "2020-05-19T13:17:20.495914152Z",
                        "ExitCode": 22,
                        "Output": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\ncurl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2020-05-19T13:17:30.50796682Z",
                        "End": "2020-05-19T13:17:30.635482465Z",
                        "ExitCode": 22,
                        "Output": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\ncurl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2020-05-19T13:17:40.654745233Z",
                        "End": "2020-05-19T13:17:40.744164595Z",
                        "ExitCode": 22,
                        "Output": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\ncurl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found\n"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Comment: Try adding `start_period: 3m` to your `healthcheck`.

Comment: I've tried with a start_period of 20s and it would still fail. Would a 3m one help? I'm thinking that if it was the case for the routes not to load the health check would also fail for a working route.

Comment: It still gets killed straight away? Not after whatever time span you allow for start-up? The 3 minutes were simply an example value.

Comment: I understand. No, it gets killed soon after it does the health checks

Comment: So what was your intention by removing the /health route but leaving the health check in? Of course your container will be unhealthy then? And swarm will attempt to fix that for you by restarting the service. But you can control that too: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy

Comment: I was not aware that the restart_policy works based on the health checks. I plan on using the health checks for automatic rollback. For example you have an update which will mess up the routes and the health check fails. It will automatically rollback to the previous version

Comment: @Ralf if I remove the `restart_policy` the container is still killed after the health check status is put to `unhealthy` and soon restarts thanks to the `replicas: 1` instruction. Who kills the container? Is the desired state by default to be 1 healthy container?

Comment: You are right. The restart policy only kicks in after the container was started successfully: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/ And yes, Swarm will attempt to reach the desired number of replicas. But you can scale back to 0 replicas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214234/discussion-between-bogdan-daniel-and-ralf).